# How to catch DOM on individual row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which includes a checkbox and mutliple input boxes in its each row.
I want to change the value of all input boxes of that row when I check the checkbox. Currently I only access the first input box.
My codes are.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='isActive'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='isActive'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='name'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and JS

```
$('body').on('click','.isActive',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().next().find('.name').val('Demian');
    }
});
```

how to solve this. JS fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/Iftakharul_alam/txpg8mhf/1/

Comment: Just so you know, binding clicks to body (or document, or other similar) is bad practice, it's better to bind as close as possible to your actual target.

Comment: `parent` goes up to the `td`, and `next` only selects the _next_ `td` after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `next()` use `parent()`

```
$('body').on('click','.isActive',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.name').val('Demian');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$('body').on('click','.isActive',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').val('Demian');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').val('');
  }
});
```

This will change all `.name` elements on the current row.

---

As j08691 pointed out, you can use the ternary operator to reduce code.

When chaining several jQuery methods together, you can separate them for legibility:

```
$('body').on('click','.isActive',function(){
  $(this)
    .closest('tr')
    .find('.name')
    .val(this.checked ? 'Demian' : '');
});
```

Note that you can refer to the `checked` property simply as `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(':checked')`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdxqmsr0/)

Comment: Thank you. Another issue, how to bind datepicker to the input box? $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}); this is not working.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with datepicker.  May be worth posting as a new question.

Comment: Actually, your code seems to work if you include the jQueryUI library:  http://jsfiddle.net/do6usepq/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `.nextAll()` instead of `.next()`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.isActive', function () {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('.name').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'Demian' : '');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/txpg8mhf/2/)**

And as you can see, you can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to reduce the amount of code.